# TypeError: HomeConsumer() takes no arguments

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-channels

I am working on channels using django, and i am having 2 different consumers for 2 differrent web pages , but while executing the web page i am getting type error for consumer

This is consumer.py file

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
    import asyncio
    
    
    class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    
        async def websocket_connect(self,event):
    
            await self.send(
                {
                    'type':'websocket.accept',
                }
            )
            print("connected",event)
    
        async def websocket_receive(self,event):
            print("received",event)
    
        async def websocket_disconnect(self,event):
            print("disconnected",event)

        

    class HomeConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    
        async def websocket_connect(self,event):
    
            await self.send(
                {
                    'type':'websocket.accept',
                }
            )
            print("connected",event)
    
        async def websocket_receive(self,event):
            print("received",event)
    
        async def websocket_disconnect(self,event):
            print("disconnected",event)
```

This is my routing.py file

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import re_path 
from .consumer import ChatConsumer,HomeConsumer
from django.conf.urls import url


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                   url(r"^profile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)",ChatConsumer), 
                   url("profile",HomeConsumer)
                ]
            )
        )
    )
    
    
})
```

THis is my websocket javascript:

```
var loc = window.location
console.log(loc)

var endpoint = "ws://" + loc.host + loc.pathname

var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("message", e)
}

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("open", e)
}

socket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("close", e)
}

socket.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("error", e)
}
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from connectedfour.views import home,game,profile

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home,name='home'),
    path('profile',profile,name='profile'),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls')),
    path('profile/<username>',game,name='game')
]
```

I am getting error like this:

```
HTTP GET /profile 200 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:50706]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /profile [127.0.0.1:50708]
Exception inside application: HomeConsumer() takes no arguments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 37, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, send, receive)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "/home/rusker/Desktop/Pydjango/tenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
TypeError: HomeConsumer() takes no arguments
WebSocket DISCONNECT /profile [127.0.0.1:50708]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try putting round brackets at the view argument to specify a class with no argument e.g. `url("profile",HomeConsumer())`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `AsyncConsumer` from the `HomeConsumer` class.

Answer (score 0):

i think in recent channels version you should write the url pattern like so.

```
url("profile", HomeConsumer.as_asgi())
```

just as you have your ".as_view()" when writing url patterns for normal class based view, because the HomeConsumer is also like a class based view.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue by using the Asgi.py, its almost same setup of routing.py but with slight change,
i refered to the article :
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html
(i used Django2.2 version of code)

also its important you make your Asgi Handler like this:

> application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
> "http": AsgiHandler(),
> 'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
> URLRouter(
> [
> url(r"^auction/(?P<room_name>[-\w]+)$", AuctionConsumer.as_asgi()),
> ]
> )
> )

})

i wish this will help anyone because i struggled for long time until i found the solution.